# Get Modal Dialog Close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form, modal-dialog

I have override new item form for list, opening myPage.aspx where this javascript is in the "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead":

```
function fGetCloseBtn() {
    var closeButton = jQuery("a[id^='DlgClose']");
    console.log(closeButton.lenght);
    }       
function fAddScriptToQueue() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fGetCloseBtn, "SP.js");
};  
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fAddScriptToQueue");
```

When page loaded, Log shows 0. Inspecting element in IE Dev Tools show that it exist. So, did I picked the wrong time to select element? Or has modal dialog other dependencies then SP.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the button on the top (X). The controls up there are part of the parent window iirc.

So try changing it to:

```
 var closeButton = jQuery("a[id^='DlgClose']",parent.document);
```

Comment: To prevent dialog from closing, I tried event.stopImmediatePropagation(); for the 'click' event of that (X) button. Doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: umh, you might look into $clearHandlers etc, post about it: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/36b68dab-5554-4137-bb32-2f9044db75d6 , don't know if it works

Answer (score 1):

To work with the SharePoint JS library you must have the SP.js at least:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js"></script>
```

Comment: As @Anders indicated, this code executes from inside dialog iframe, so all dependencies allready here. It is even unnecessary to call `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fGetCloseBtn, "SP.js");`