# Refresh parent page after closing list item dialog

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, splistitem, modal-dialog, splist

I'm trying to refresh the parent page of a list when closing the dialog of a list item.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with `javascript` somehow?

I inspected the button in the `DOM` and tried to write a `jQuery` listener for the button's class, but it did not work:

```
$(".ms-dlgCloseBtn").click(function() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel);
});
```

Advise the best way to achieve the desired functionality.

**UPDATE**

The dialogs are custom WebParts that have been attached to the list. The dialogs are launched via OOB functionality. I am not manually opening the dialog.

Comment: This question might be a similar issue as you have: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68289/get-modal-dialog-close-button/68318

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the event is attached only to elements that are loaded into DOM. Dialog is generated dynamically.

Hence we need jQuery to attach click event to element having style `ms-dlgCloseBtn` whenever it gets loaded to DOM

```
jQuery('.ms-dlgCloseBtn').live('click',function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: I have to use `.on()` since I am using > jQuery 1.9, but I am still not getting a response. 

`$("body").on("click", ".ms-dlgCloseBtn", function () {
        alert("test");
    });`

Comment: Try `jQuery('.ms-dlgCloseBtn').on('click',function() {
    alert('test');
});`

Comment: I am still unable to launch the alert dialog per clicking the 'x' and your solution above.

Comment: Can anyone out there suggest a possible server side option then?